# can I move some space from from /dev/sda3 (home) to /dev/sda2 (root) without losing any data or reinstalling the os?

Tags: lubuntu, disk-management

This is a problem I'm facing because my root space is running low.

[image]

Comment: Please, instead of relying on a screenshot, copy-paste the terminal output into your post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you probably can, but not from your currently booted system. One **CANNOT** mess with a disk's partitions while any of the disk's partitions is mounted.

Backup your system before you start.

You'll have to boot from your install medium in "Try Ubuntu" mode, or a Live distribution. You can download a purpose-built distribution from https://gparted.org/ which also has documentation.

Ensure that your system is plugged in. This is not something to do on bsttery power.

Once booted, run `gparted`.

Use the box at the upper right of the `gparted` screen to select your disk. Be sure to pick the right disk.

Select the `sda3` partition (the donor). Slide the left edge of `sda3` to the right, creating available (unallocated) disk space between `sda3` and `sda2`. This is the space to be donated, I recommend   20GB, at least. You don't want to do this procedure often.

Select the `sda2` partition (the recipient). Slide the right edge of `sda2` right to cover the unallocated space.

Take a calming breath, and inspect what `gparted` is about to do. There's a lot of disk block juggling, be prepared to wait.

Click the checkmark to start the process. You can either watch `gparted` grind, or go out and play.

When `gparted` finishes, look at the `gparted` resultd, shutdown your system, remove the `gparted` boot medium, and reboot.

Read `man gparted parted`.